# Is the space of prob. measures with same mean a lattice?

Tags: stochastic-processes, lattice-orders

Let $(S,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space and $\mu$ an arbitrary probability measure for $(S,\Sigma)$. Consider the set of all probability measures for that space with same mean $p$:

$\mathcal{S}(p)=\{\mu\in(S,\Sigma): \int_{S} s\mu(ds)=p\}$.

Endow this measurable space with the first-order stochastic dominance order, that is, $\mu'\succsim_{FOSD}\mu$ if for every increasing, bounded function $f: S\to\mathbb{R}$, it holds that $\int_{S}f(s)\mu'(ds)\ge \int_{S}f(s)\mu(ds)$.

**Question: is $\mathcal{S}(p)$ a lattice?**

Comment: A remark, as $s$ is trivially increasing two measures cannot be in $\mathcal{S}(p)$ and have $\mu'\succsim_{FOSD}\mu$ and have $\int_{S}f(s)\mu'(ds)> \int_{S}f(s)\mu(ds)$ they must coincide for the function $f(s)=s$.

Comment: Agreed! but you could have either $\mu'\vee \mu$ or  $\mu'\wedge \mu$ being different from $\mu'$ and $\mu$, right? The question then is about $\mathbb{E}_{\mu'\vee \mu}[s]=\mathbb{E}_{\mu'\wedge \mu}[s]=p$ being necessarily true. This could be a trivial one and I'm not seeing it right.

Comment: But how do you define  $\mu \wedge \mu'$ or $\mu \vee \mu'$ for let's a simple set $A$ like an open interval $(a,b)$ on $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: In this case, it is known that $\mu\sucssim\mu'$ if and only if $F_{\mu'}(s)\ge F_{\mu}(s)$ where $F_{\mu}, F_{\mu'}$ are the associated distribution functions of the measures. Define the distribution $F_{\mu \vee \mu'}(s)=\min\{F_{\mu'}(s), F_{\mu}(s)\}$. From it, we can come up with the measure $\mu\vee \mu'$. I am following arguments from Muller and Scarsini (2006), Stochastic Order Relations and Lattices on Probability Measures.

Comment: Ok I get it now (shouldn't it be the max though instead of the min ?)

Comment: For $\mu'\vee \mu$ we should use min and for $\mu'\wedge \mu$ the max. If we want to define in terms of survival distributions instead, then the more intuitive association between $\vee$ and max holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal S _(p)$ is not a lattice unless mistaken.

Take $\mu$ a measure loading points $0$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$ and $\mu'$ loading points $1/4$ and $5/8$ respectively with probabilities $1/3$ and $2/3$. Then $\mu \wedge \mu'$ loads point $0 $ with mass $1/2$ then point $1/4$ at another $1/3$ probability and finally point $1$ with what's left so at $1/6=(1-(1/2+1/3))$
Now let's integrate $\mu$ and $\mu'$ and $\mu \wedge \mu'$  over $X$
$$E_\mu[X]=1/2$$
$$E_\mu'[X]=1/3*1/4 +2/3*5/4 =1/2$$
So they both are in $\mathcal S_(1/2)$

But $E_{\mu'\wedge \mu} [X]=1/3*1/4+ 1/6*1=1/4$ is in $\mathcal S _(1/4)$

So it's not a lattice
I took the definition of $\mu \wedge \mu'(s)=max(\mu(s),\mu'(s))$

Comment: You're right! Thank you for the counter-example.